# Do any Pokemon give birth to a species that is not part of its evolution?

Tags: pokemon

In Pokemon FireRed, [this text is found](https://iimarckus.org/dumps/dfirered.txt):

> MEW gave birth.
>
> We named the newborn MEWTWO.

[Another question on this site asks if this is literal](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/227174/in-the-games-did-mew-literally-give-birth-to-mewtwo). I want to know, assuming it is, are there any other instances of Pokemon giving birth to a different Pokemon that is not part of its evolutionary cycle?

Comment: Anime or games?

Comment: @A.bakker both.

Comment: Do eggs count as birth?

Comment: What about Ditto?

Comment: @Oni Is ditto the male or the female?

Comment: @TheAsh Ditto is actually genderless, and you can't breed eggs of it. but when it is paired with a male or female of any kind, it produces eggs with that male/female that hatch into the male/female's species.

Comment: @f So I wouldn't count that. There one parent is clearly the same species.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Manaphy and Phione

There are a pair of legendary Pokémon that are like this: [Manaphy](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Manaphy_(Pok%C3%A9mon)), when paired with a Ditto, produces a [Phione](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Phione_(Pok%C3%A9mon)) egg. They do not evolve.

### Illumise and Volbeat: Honorable Mention 1

[Illumise](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Illumise_(Pok%C3%A9mon)) and Ditto can produce [Volbeat](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Volbeat_(Pok%C3%A9mon)) eggs, and vice versa. They do not evolve.

### Nidoran Lines: Honorable Mention 2

[Nidoran♂](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Nidoran%E2%99%82_(Pok%C3%A9mon)) paired with a Ditto can make a [Nidoran♀](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Nidoran%E2%99%80_(Pok%C3%A9mon)) egg), for example. See the [full chart](https://pokemondb.net/pokebase/280363/how-to-breed-nidoran-male?show=280364#a280364) to see what combinations work.

### Gender-blocked evolutions

Some evolutions require a certain gender of Pokémon, but will produce offspring of both genders. A [Vespiquen](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Vespiquen_(Pok%C3%A9mon)), for example, can produce eggs that contain male Combee, which do not evolve.

### Same dex number, different forms

Due to the way regional forms work, it is possible for a parent to produce offspring that cannot evolve into the same form it is.

- Breeding regular Ponyta will produce Galarian Ponyta eggs in Galar, for example. Same for Pokémon like regular Sandshrew in Alola.
- Pokémon like Raichu (which don't have a regional pre-evolution) are an interesting case, as the Pikachu offspring of a regular Raichu can only evolve into Alolan Raichu if in Alola, while an Alolan Raichu will produce regular Pikachus that will evolve into regular Raichus when not in Alola (so far, this means Galar).

---

I don’t remember any of this coming up outside of the main games, and the honorable mentions only work as of gen 5.

In all other cases, the bred egg will be the same species, or a pre-evolution of one of the parents. Both parents don’t need to be the same species, however.

Comment: I think Miltank and Tauros behave similarly to Illumise and Volbeat?

Comment: @Stef It would make sense, but I don’t believe that’s true. The sources online I’ve read say it doesn’t work. Also, compare Bulbapedia’s wording about [Tauros](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Tauros_(Pok%C3%A9mon)) with Illumise for example.

Comment: I believe a Persian in Galar region would fit the bill too. If breeding produces regional variant, then that means the offspring would evolve into Perrserker

Answer (score 12):

Well, if you are talking about the anime...

It is implied in the Pokemon movie Mewtwo Returns that the clones Nidoqueen & Rhyhorn have children together.

Besides that in the games...

Pokemon can breed depending on their [Egg Group](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Egg_Group), making species (and therefore evolutionary line) irrelevant.

[image: Pokémon: Mewtwo Returns screen cap showing rhyhorn and nidoqueen adults and children]

Comment: Is that a.... baby nidoqueen??

Comment: @C_Z_ yea, there is an ongoing discussion if this is one of the many ,many, many anime mistakes...or that clone breeding works different from regular Pokémon breeding.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are good, but I wanted to add a couple of notes.

#### Ditto breeding

Ditto is the go-to for the lazy breeder (like me), and can breed with both males and females. Ditto is genderless, but takes on the gender opposite of its partner, and thus carries the eggs if paired with a male or fertilizes if paired with a female.

Ditto can't be bred and must be caught wild. But it can produce offspring of nearly any other type besides itself.

#### Egg groups

In the event that two gendered Pokemon produce an egg, the egg will be of the female's species (most of the time; there are exceptions that others have already said). But the male/female parents don't need to be the same species. They simply need to be of the same "breeding group":

- Amorphous
- Bug
- Dragon
- Fairy
- Field
- Flying
- Grass
- Human-Like
- Mineral
- Monster
- Undiscovered
- Water 1
- Water 2
- Water 3

#### Braviary and Mandibuzz, an example

Some Pokemon only have 1 gender, such as Braviary (male only) and Mandibuzz (female) so if they're bred or paired together, they will produce offspring that are of the female species. The only way to breed the male species is through Ditto.