# Do all Pokemon come from eggs? Or are some born?

Tags: pokemon

In Pokemon FireRed, [this text is found](https://iimarckus.org/dumps/dfirered.txt):

> MEW gave birth.
>
> We named the newborn MEWTWO.

[Another question on this site asks if this is literal](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/227174/in-the-games-did-mew-literally-give-birth-to-mewtwo). I want to know, assuming it is, are there any other instances of Pokemon giving birth instead of hatching from an egg?

Comment: Never been a live birth in the pokemon universe as of this moment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Mew didn’t give birth… anymore

Out of universe, the text you quote comes from a time before in-game breeding, Pokémon eggs, or anything of the sort. And while the same text from the first gen games about "giving birth" can be found in FRLG (where there is breeding), it doesn’t appear anywhere else. In LGPE, "We obtained a new Pokémon from Mew" while in the Pokémon Origins anime it’s "From the potential within Mew, we have managed to create an entirely new Pokémon: Mewtwo." To the best of my knowledge, Mew was the only time that a Pokémon was said to have given birth, but now it’s retconned away.

### Other methods of creation

There are plenty of examples of Pokémon that are said by their Pokédex entries to be created through methods other than eggs, though many of them also hatch from eggs. Off the top of my head:

- Porygon (man-made)
- Many ghosts (such as Banette, originally a doll)
- Exeggcute (heads can fall off Exeggutor and form a group)

Many legendaries were said to have been created. For example, in the [Sinnoh myths](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Sinnoh_myths), Arceus (who did hatch from an egg) created the lake trio, and Dialga and Palkia:

> Having tumbled from the vortex, the Egg gave rise to the Original One.
> From itself, two beings the Original One did make.
> Time started to spin. Space began to expand.
> From itself again, three living things the Original One did make.

Comment: Trubbish is spontaneously generated.

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to believe Mew ever "gave birth" in the mammal sense or that this was "retconned". Imagine you're a scientist in the research lab that created Mewtwo. The creation of Mewtwo is a huuuuge accomplishment. Of course in the lab's journal, you're going to write it as a short and classy punchline such as "Mew gave birth". That doesn't imply that Mew was a female mammal who delivered Mewtwo from a womb.

Answer (score 3):

There are several other instances in which Pokemon are born not from an egg.

some of these are legendary like

- [**Groudon**](https://pokemon.fandom.com/wiki/Groudon): Formed by tectonic action.
- [**Kyogre**](https://pokemon.fandom.com/wiki/Kyogre): Born from the insane water pressures at the depth of the ocean.
- [**The Ruinous Quartet**](https://pokemon.fandom.com/wiki/Ruinous_Quartet): The 4 Paldean treasures being "possessed" by emotion and becoming a Pokemon.